# My Rspec test refuses to run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#code:pages_controller_spec_title

My code is as follows. When uncommented the test wont run. Below is the commented version of the code that allows the defined test to initiate. I don't know how to format this question with ruby syntax color. Dont yell at me.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static Pages" do
  describe "Home page" do
    it "should have the h1 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      page.should have_selector('h1', :text =>'Sample App')  
    end
    it "should have the title 'Home'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      page.should have_selector('title',
       :text => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home")  
    end   
  end

  describe "Help Page" do
    it "should have the h1 'Help'" do
      visit '/static_pages/help'
      page.should have_selector('h1', :text =>'Help')
    end
    it "should have the title 'Help'" do
      visit '/static_pages/help'
      page.should have_selector('title', 
      :text => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help")
    end
  end

  describe "About Page" do
    it "should have the h1 'About us'" do
      visit '/static_pages/about'
      page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'About us')
    end
    it "should have the title 'About us'" do
      visit '/static_pages/about'
      page.should have_selector('title', 
      :text => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About us")
    end  
  end

  # describe 'Contact' do
  #     it "Should have the h1 'Contact'" do
  #       visit "static_pages/contact"
  #       page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'Contact')
  #     end
  #     it "should have the title 'Contact'"
  #       visit "static_pages/contact"
  #       page.should have_selector('title',
  #       :text => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Contact")
  #     end
  #   end      
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you forgot `do` at the end of this line:

```
 it "should have the title 'Contact'" 
                                       ^
```

Comment: Man, tired eyes. Lesson learned, sometimes its good to sleep on it. Thanks for taking a look.